# Can I use other languages(other than JavaScript) to create Gnome Shell Extensions?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I am creating a GNOME Shell Extension and want to use languages like C++/Golang rather than JavaScript to create it. It is also acceptable if I can somehow call/use the C++/go executable in my `extension.js`. Please tell me if this is even possible and if yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

You can't ship binaries with a GNOME Shell extension, because they are architecture dependent and can't be properly reviewed. You could write a library with [GObject-Introspection](https://gi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and ship that separately, but still not bundled in an extension for the same reason.

If you're tempted to ship a binary with a GNOME Shell extension, there's a good chance you should just be writing an application.

Comment: How about languages that can be "compiled" to javascript and support calling JS APIs from the code?

https://pub.dev/packages/js
https://dart.dev/tools/dart2js

In theory - it looks like it should work. But I didn't find that anybody tried it.

Comment: As long as the submitted extension code is in JavaScript that can be reviewed (ie. not minified or obfuscated), it doesn't really matter how you get there.